# sql-server OPENJSON ways to parse multiple array value elements as one element?

Tags: arrays, sql-server, t-sql, parsing, open-json

Is there is any other (more pretty) way to accomplish the following?

I am struggling with a way to display multiple elements of an array as one element.

I have a JSON-string, that looks like this:

```
DECLARE @JSON nvarchar(max)
SELECT @JSON = N'{"firstNames": ["Bengt","Erik"]}'
```

I would like it to be formatted like this:

```
| firstNames |
| ---------- |
| Bengt Erik |
```

This approach:

```
SELECT value as firstNames FROM OPENJSON (@JSON, '$.firstNames')
```

results in

```
| firstNames |
| ---------- |
| Bengt      |
| Erik       |
```

So I tried:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(value,',',' '),'"',''),'[',''),']','') as firstNames 
FROM OPENJSON (@JSON, '$')
```

And yes, it does give me the result I want, but can this be done in another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could aggregate the First Names after you receive them:

```sql
SELECT STRING_AGG(value,' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY [key]) as firstNames
FROM OPENJSON (@JSON, '$.firstNames');
```